# S3 Cross Account Sync - Cannot sync source encrypted objects to destination

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-kms

I want to sync data from my Dev Account S3 Bucket (dev-bucket) to Prod Account S3 Bucket(prod-bucket).
Some of the objects are encrypted in the dev-bucket and other are non encrypted. I am able to sync the non encrypted data to the prod-bucket, but I am not able to sync the encrypted objects.
I am getting the following error :

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the CopyObject operation: The encryption parameters are not applicable to this object.
```

I am using the following command to sync the buckets :

```
aws s3 sync s3://dev-bucket/ s3://prod-bucket/ --sse-c-copy-source AES256 --sse-c-copy-source-key 'dev-account-customer-managed-key'
```

Process Snapshot :

[image]

What I am doing wrong in the command ?

Comment: Which account is the EC2 instance in, dev or prod?

Comment: It is under Prod Account

Comment: Can you copy individual encrypted objects using AWS S3 cp?

Comment: Nope I have not tried with CP , but yes for non encrypted file the sync is working.I tried it using single file in Bucket. Is this a issue with respect  to KMS ? I am not sure.

Comment: I executed CP and it is working.

Comment: Now I executed sync again and it is working and I am able to download data from Prod Account and able to see the data. How can this be possible.
New command :

`aws s3 sync s3://dev-bucket/ s3://prod-bucket/`

Comment: I think that `--sse-c-copy-source-key` requires the actual contents of the Key, not the name of a key. Or is that what you were doing anyway?